# How to work with Route and Link in two Components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

[This will be my full view both components together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0fQT.png) 
i have created two components one for the side bar and one for the main view. i have my Link in side bar Components and Route in main view Component. my problem is do i need to put both of them in one Router (BrowserRouter) or can i use two Routers in two components.

When i use Route and Link in same Router like this it works fine.
this is my Main View

```
render() {
        return (
            <div > 
               <Router>
                <SideBar  />
                <div className="content-page">
                    <div className="content">
                        <TopBar/>


                                <Route exact path={'/home'} component={Index}/>
                                <Route exact path={'/user'} component={User}/>

                        </Router>
                    </div>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
             </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Is it possible to use two Routers in both Components when i use it it doesn't work.
This is my Main View and  contain the links.

```
render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <SideBar  />
                <div className="content-page">
                    <div className="content">
                        <TopBar/>
                        <Router>

                                <Route exact path={'/home'} component={Index}/>
                                <Route exact path={'/user'} component={User}/>

                        </Router>
                    </div>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

This is my SideBar

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
<Router>
                 <Link to={'/home'} >Home</Link>
</Router>
            </div>
}
```

Is it possible to use two Router (BrowserRouter) or i have to use only one. if i have to use only one, is it fine to use with huge content in it.

Comment: yes its fine to use one router for huge content,Router is parent Wrapper component for routing

Comment: thank you kishan I m new to React so can i know is it possible to use two Routers in two components and work as one

Comment: @Ksamanpriya i posted a sample component for react routing check that for your better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444077/6544460.

Answer (score -1):

*demo application using **react router dom***

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}
```

for better understanding concept, try to go through official [reacttraining.com](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: This is something i have already know. the thing i want to know is is it possible to use Two Components one with Link and One with Route inside two Routers(BrowserRouter) and work as one. if its possible how to do that. Thank you

Comment: @Ksamanpriya can you share screenshot of your requirement for more clarification. what exactly are you creating.?

Comment: I have added a picture to the question please can you refer it.