# How can I write Link and Route in different component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, router

I want to use Link and Route in a different component to use the Header component as a navbar but that is not working. This is my code but the link is not working to change between the components in Reactjs.

```
App.js

import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';
import Body from './Body';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Header></Header>
          <Body></Body>         
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;


Header.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/doc">Doc</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
export default Header;

Body.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Doc from './Doc';

class Body extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home} ></Route>
                <Route path="/doc" component={Doc} ></Route>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
export default Body;

Home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Home</h1>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;

Doc.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Doc extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Doc</h1>
        )
    }
}
export default Doc;
```

**Note**: I checked out this link but this doesn't suffice my answer. 
[How to work with Route and Link in two Components in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443881/how-to-work-with-route-and-link-in-two-components-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the modules incorrectly.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

should be:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

should be:

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Link and Route are separate components, you are importing them as BrowserRouter, which only imports BrowserRouter with an alias.

The one time you would want to do this is when importing the BrowserRouter as Router, for sematic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this following line in your **`Header`** class component

```
import {BrowserRouter as Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

to

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

And in you **`Body`** class component change

```
import {BrowserRouter as Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

to

```
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by wrong imports in Headers.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

It should be:

```
 import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

you can see working example of the fixed problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-morning-hz8s2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)